# View last transaction made by sales rep at the end of every day during last week

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm familiar to SQL but new to crystal report.

I have a table which contains all the transaction made by every sales rep in a store, the fields are as follows:

```
RepName, transactionDateTime, transactionAmount
```

This table contains data that contains every transaction detail made by every sales rep for the entire month of January.

I want to filter in Crystal report such that I get the following:
For every sales rep, I want to see the LAST transaction made everyday before the day ends, during last week. If a sales rep is not working that day, he/she will not have a "last transction made during that day" thus the row will show blank at the transactionAmount field

For example:

```
RepName, TransactionDateTime, TransactionAmount
John, Sun, $10
John, Mon, $5
John, Tues, $1
John, Wed, $6
John, Thurs, $7
John, Fri, (blank)        <--- John did not work on Friday, thus no value here
John, Sat, $10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place the fields in detail section and set the `supress blank section` for detail section in section expert.

Comment: But the sales rep could make multiple transaction during that day. How do I view the "last" transaction he made during that day?

Comment: You can group by sales representative and then place date in details then take maximum of date